# For which values of $z \in \mathbb{C} $ do we have $ A_2 (z) = 0 $?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$ \forall z \in \mathbb{C} $ : $ e^{ jz} = \displaystyle \sum_{ n \geq 0 } \dfrac{ (jz)^{n} }{n!} = \displaystyle \sum_{ n \geq 0 } \dfrac{ x^{3n} }{ (3n)!} + j \displaystyle \sum_{ n \geq 0 } \dfrac{ x^{3n+1} }{ (3n+1)!} + j^2 \displaystyle \sum_{ n \geq 0 } \dfrac{ x^{3n+2} }{ (3n+2)!} = A_0 (z ) + j A_1 (z) + j^2 A_2 (z) $
with :
$ \begin{cases} A_0 (z) = \displaystyle \sum_{ n \geq 0 } \dfrac{ x^{3n} }{ (3n)!} \\ A_1 (z) = \displaystyle \sum_{ n \geq 0 } \dfrac{ x^{3n+1} }{ (3n+1)!} \\ A_2 (z) = \displaystyle \sum_{ n \geq 0 } \dfrac{ x^{3n+2} }{ (3n+2)!} \end{cases} $ and : $ j = e^{ i \frac{ 2 \pi }{ 3 } } $.

Could someone tell me for which $ z \in \mathbb{C} $, do we have : $ e^{ jz} = A_0 (z ) + j A_1 (z) $  ( i.e : $ A_2 (z) = 0 $ ) ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is confusing...again: is $\;j=i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ ? All your taggins are from mathematics and thus we use $\;i\;$ and not $\;j\;$, like some physics and engineers, particularly in electricity.

Comment: ??? You already said $e^{jz} = A_0(z) + j A_1(z) + j^2 A_2(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$.  What does that have to do with $A_2(z) = 0$?

Comment: @Juanpemo : $ j = e^{ i \dfrac{ 2 \pi }{3} } $.

Comment: @Robert : sorry ! I corrected the mistake. :) see above.

Comment: Why is the index of  the  first sum starting from 1, what is x ?

Comment: Sorry. I corrected again.  :)

Answer (score 2):

$$A_2(x) = \dfrac{e^{x}}{3} - \dfrac{e^{-x/2}}{3} \left(\cos(\sqrt{3} x/2) + \sqrt{3} \sin(\sqrt{3} x/2)\right) = \dfrac{e^x}{3} + j \dfrac{ e^{jx}}{3} + j^2 \dfrac{e^{j^2 x}}{3}$$
Note that $A_2(jx) = j^2 A_2(x)$, so the set of zeros will be invariant under rotation by $2\pi/3$.  It appears that they are all on the 
negative real axis and its rotations by $\pm 2\pi/3$. One zero, of course, is $x=0$.
The other zeros on the negative real axis are near $-(6k+7) \sqrt{3} \pi/9$ for nonnegative integers $k$.  The first few of these are approximately
$$ \eqalign{-4.233207192,& -7.859792867, -11.48739599, -15.11499470,\cr -18.74259343,& -22.37019216, -25.99779089, -29.62538962,\cr -33.25298834,& -36.88058707, -40.50818580, -44.13578453}$$